# Javascript/node.js retrieving value from dictionary key which is in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I've never asked a question on here but here goes.

Lets say I have an array (named `whatever`) that looks like this when displayed:

`[[{name: "Joe", price: 42}],[{name: "Smith", price: 34}],[{name: "Jerry", price: 67}]]`

And I want to do something like `whatever[1].price` (this fails in my program) I want to be able to take one of the arrays in whatever and retrieve it like  whatever[1].price. Any way to do this similar to an `ArrayName[index].key` ?

Comment: `whatever[1].price` ... well, whatever[1] is an array /// so `whatever[1][0].price`

Answer (score 0):

first, your JSON is not correct, see the updated one;

since inner element of array is an array with single item so you can access it with 0 index.

```js
var test =  [[{name: "Joe", price: 42}],[{name: "Smith", price: 34}],[{name: "Jerry", price: 67}]];


test.forEach(item=> {
  console.log(item[0]['price'])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does an Array of Objects be stored in an another array? Just remove the extra array initialization if you just want to achieve this

> And I want to do something like whatever[1].price

Change the data like this:

```
[{name: "Joe", price: 42}],[{name: "Smith", price: 34}],[{name: "Jerry", price: 67}]
```

If you can't change the data, then A.T.'s solution will suffice

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on your response ( which have an unnecessary array which contain an array of objects ) you can access to your data like

```
whatever[0][0].price
```

The better way is to change your response in backend to get an array of objects then you can access it like normal

```
whatever[0].price
```